# Gitextensions with ssh and password

Tags: git, ssh, windows-10, putty, git-extensions

I just installed gitextensions on win10. At the first fetch of a repos, it showed a terminal window to set password or so. I did something wrong, but cannot get back these windows.

Now i get this error whenever accessing the remote repos:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@
```

I deleted the gitextensions user-dir, but that didn't help. I searched all settings so I could reset something to get the terminal window back when fetching the first time. 
When searching here and on google on this error, i only see the solutions to set ssh-keys. But I want to use username/password.

Gitextensions is configured to use putty.

When using the terminal window in gitextensions I get the same error. But when using git-bash, git is responding normally and asking for the password.

The remotes are on our server and protected by ssh-users. The url we use is:

```
username@ip-address:path/to/repos.git
```

Other answers advised to use the URL 'ssh://username:password@host/path/to/repos.git'. I tried that also, but that doesn't work. Then git-bash also cannot connect to the remote.

Can gitextensions handle a password for ssh? Or not?
How can i fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using openssh instead of putty in gitextensions? this is available in the settings. This seems to work for me.

Comment: Git Extensions has a ridiculous array of options for connecting to a remote, the permutations of settings run to thousands and 99% of them do not work, so you are basically blindly trying settings until you get lucky. I have tried to bring this to the attention of the developers but they are too busy polishing the bells and whistles. Please post an answer to your question if you found one.

Comment: @bikeman868 sorry for not responding sooner. I overlooked your comment. I did not find an answer, sadly. Mostly I work with netbeans with git and there passwords are saved. But it is slower then git. But it works...